# Twilio <Pay> Error: No callsid in the DTMF message

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

When I'm trying to make a test call from TwiML Apps page (https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/runtime/twiml-apps/) for Pay TwiML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Pay/>
</Response>
```

During pressing of first DTMF button I get error message `No callsid in the DTMF message` and end of call.

Has anyone met such a problem?

Comment: Are you able to test by connecting a phone number directly to the webhook endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

## Solved!

`PCI Mode` should be set to `Enabled`.

[image: PCI Mode = Enabled]

*Such an unobvious error response :(*